# Is there a term or a word specifically applying to favoritism towards foreigners than local citizens?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

I am looking for some kind of term that relates to say, 
opposite of nepotism??? im not sure.
or opposite of ethnic nepotism.
but the situation is that " person X is From Y and will prioritize someone from any other country or region but place Y, in fact there is more favouritism to people of place A, B, C... etc BUT LOCAL CITIZENS OF PLACE Y ARE PUT BEHIND THEM.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just mean [positive discrimination?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/positive-discrimination) There might be an evolutionary / anthropological term for *favouring more distantly related mates for reproductive purposes,* for example, but even if such a word *did* exist, would that suit your context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers but positive discrimination is "the act of giving an advantage to those groups in society that are often treated unfairly because of their race, sex, etc." it doesn't suit the context of my paper because we don't know if foreigners are treated unfairly because, in the particular case, foreigners are given better opportunities than locals by "other locals of authority".   but thank you though, I have more options to look through now.

Comment: You should perhaps note that Google reports thousands of instances of ["immigrant-friendly policies"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22immigrant-friendly+policies%22&oq=%22immigrant-friendly+policies%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.10587j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but the rather weird-sounding ["xenophilic policies"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22xenophilic+policies%22&oq=%22xenophilic+policies%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.9984j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets just a couple of dozen hits.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

**"a xenophile"** is a person attracted to foreign people, foreign culture, etc.  Although not half as common as its opposite word, "xenophobe", it seems like a good fit here.

definition:

> - "a person who likes foreigners or things foreign." [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/xenophile)
> - "one attracted to foreign things, such as styles or people."  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophile)

From the web:

- I'm really interested in other religions and think of myself as a xenophile, which means I love things and people who are different than myself.
- As a nation, are we xenophiles?

Comment: thank you, thats a good one. i was wondering if i can use it in a negative form. like in a case its not good to be prioritizing foreigners instead of locals since locals dont get any chance but being "xenophilic" puts it in a positive way.

Comment: @Samiha  Sure you can.  If you are a xenophile, you will inevitably reject a better national every now and then.